# Export links from POST to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[ID]/copy stopped working

Tags: google-docs-api

Starting January 25, 2021 at about 20:00 UTC, the export links that are returned from creating files stopped working.

Before that time we were able to reliably POST a new file and get back something like

```
...
"exportLinks": {
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=blahblahblah&exportFormat=pdf"
 }
...
```

and then use that URL to download the document. We'd get response codes of 302 or 307. However, at 2021-01-25 20:00 UTC we starting getting several 500's.

This seems to most often happen when a doc is created from that `copy` endpoint, but not exclusively.

Did something change in the API at that time?

Comment: Can you share some more repro steps? Did it only happen with particular files? 500 error would suggest a server error and so maybe intermittent. Is this still an issue?

Comment: Repro steps:

1) Copy an old file to a new file with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[ID]/copy?convert=true&supportsAllDrives=true`

2) Not sure if it's necessary, but we've been then replacing some text in the new document with `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/[ID]:batchUpdate`

3) Set permissions at `permissions` endpoint to type:anyone, role:reader

4) Try to use that export/pdf link

NOTE: The last such error was 24 hours ago, so Google seems to have fixed this bug

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a temporary error on server side. So its not an issue with your code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500 - if you experience a long outage, best place to post is the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)